# No generic method 'ThenBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable'

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I'm trying to create a generic **OrderBy**(fields collection) method to use in a new EF .Net Core 2.1 and managed to write the below code:

```
 public static Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> GetOrderByFunction(List<SortColumn> columns)
 {
            Type typeQueryable = typeof(IQueryable<TEntity>);
            ParameterExpression argQueryable = Expression.Parameter(typeQueryable, "p");
            LambdaExpression outerExpression = Expression.Lambda(argQueryable, argQueryable);
            Type entityType = typeof(TEntity);

            ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
            Expression expr = arg;

            Expression resultExp = null;

            foreach (SortColumn sc in columns)
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = entityType.GetProperty(sc.FieldName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                Expression propertyExpr = Expression.Property(expr, pi);
                Type propertyType = pi.PropertyType;
                LambdaExpression lambdaExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyExpr, arg);
                String methodName = string.Empty;

                if (resultExp != null)
                {
                    methodName = sc.Descending ? "ThenBy" : "ThenByDescending";

                    /// No generic method 'ThenBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments.
                    /// No type arguments should be provided if the method is non - generic.
                    Expression exp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, new Type[] { entityType, propertyType }, outerExpression.Body, Expression.Quote(lambdaExp));

                    MethodInfo minfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).First(m => m.Name == methodName);

                    /// Method System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1
                    /// [TSource] OrderBy[TSource,TKey](System.Linq.IQueryable`1
                    /// [TSource],System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1
                    /// [System.Func`2[TSource,TKey]]) is a generic method definition
                    /// Parameter name: method
                    resultExp = Expression.Call(minfo, exp, resultExp);
                }
                else
                {
                    methodName = sc.Descending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
                    resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, new Type[] { entityType, propertyType }, outerExpression.Body, Expression.Quote(lambdaExp));
                }
            }

            LambdaExpression orderedLambda = Expression.Lambda(resultExp, argQueryable);
            return (Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>)orderedLambda.Compile();
        }
```

My `Sortcolumn` class just hold the field name and order direction.

```
public class SortColumn
{
    public string FieldName { get; }
    public bool Descending { get; }

    public SortColumn(string fieldName, bool descending)
    {
        FieldName = fieldName;
        Descending = descending;
    }
}
```

It works when my collection has only a single item like Id or Description but fails to sort by more than one field.

The errors I got are commented in the snippet:

> No generic method 'ThenBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments
>   and arguments.
>   No type arguments should be provided if the method is non - generic.

It's strange because it works fine for the `OrderBy` command.
But even if I pass the `OrderBy` I was unable to "join" the methods to assemble a unique expression. The error I got is:

> Method System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable'1 [TSource]
>   OrderBy[TSource,TKey](System.Linq.IQueryable'1
>   [TSource],System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'1
>   [System.Func'2[TSource,TKey]]) is a generic method definition
>   Parameter name: method

Things I tried:
Change `typeof(Queryable)` to use `Enumerable` or `EnumerableQuery` or even List, Use invoke, etc.

My goal is to dynamicaly pass a list of fields to order my GetAll() methods for my domain objects building a delegate function can give me something like:

```
            var test = new List<TEntity>();
            test.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ThenByDescending(x => x.Description);
```

Comment: Aren't you [reinventing a wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/861716)? Also, I wonder why you create a `Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>`. I think this type of expression modifiers is more versatile in the form of extension methods.

Comment: You might want to check out [MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io/).  It has its own [ThenBy](https://morelinq.github.io/2.8/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_ThenBy.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you are overcomplicating everything:

```
// Or IEnumerable<SortColumn> columns
public static Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> GetOrderByFunction<TEntity>(params SortColumn[] columns)
{
    Type typeQueryable = typeof(IQueryable<TEntity>);
    ParameterExpression argQueryable = Expression.Parameter(typeQueryable, "p");
    Type entityType = typeof(TEntity);

    ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");

    Expression resultExp = argQueryable;

    bool first = true;

    foreach (SortColumn sc in columns)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = entityType.GetProperty(sc.FieldName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Expression propertyExpr = Expression.Property(arg, pi);
        Type propertyType = pi.PropertyType;
        LambdaExpression lambdaExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyExpr, arg);

        string methodName;

        if (first)
        {
            first = false;

            methodName = sc.Descending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        }
        else
        {
            methodName = sc.Descending ? "ThenBy" : "ThenByDescending";
        }

        resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, new Type[] { entityType, propertyType }, resultExp, Expression.Quote(lambdaExp));
    }

    // Case empty columns: simply append a .OrderBy(x => true)
    if (first)
    {
        LambdaExpression lambdaExp = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(true), arg);
        resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { entityType, typeof(bool) }, resultExp, Expression.Quote(lambdaExp));
    }

    LambdaExpression orderedLambda = Expression.Lambda(resultExp, argQueryable);
    return (Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>)orderedLambda.Compile();
}
```

I'll add that calling `FieldName` what is really a `PropertyName` is a little... misleading :-)

Note that I've added the case for when `columns` is empty: this because you return a `IOrderedQueryable`, so an ordering must always be present.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Yes it's a bit more complicated than the usual we do here but we are exploring a new approach and finally using EF so we want to test regarding to performance