# How can I use func in a C# EF dbquery statement for sorting?

Tags: linq, func

I have to do multi-part sorts and want to do it dynamically.

I found this question but do not know how to use `func` in a dbquery statement.

[No generic method 'ThenBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976899/no-generic-method-thenby-on-type-system-linq-queryable/54449084#54449084)

If I could get the code in the thread to work it would be nirvana.

All the examples I have seen use `then` within a `where` statement, but I need to use the function to do sorting.

I have written extensions using IQueryable, including ones for orderby and orderbydescending. The problem is `thenby` and `thenbydescending` use `iorderedqueryable`.

The error I get when using ThenByProperty is

Object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[ORMModel.v_Brand]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[ORMModel.v_Brand]'.

Do not get such an error when I use a comparable OrderByProperty extension.

what a mess, obviously I do not post often here. Anyway I am stumped and clueless so any tips are very appreciated.

Tried to post code but kept getting format errors so gave up. But help me anyways :)

Comment: I think it's the correct behavior, you can't use `ThenBy` without `OrderBy` => `dataset.OrderBy().ThenBy()`

Comment: Instead of doing the multi sort on the server side, I would take the result from the server and then do the sort locally: `dbContext.Items.Where(item => item.ID < 20).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(item => item.LastName).ThenBy(item => item.FirstName)`. The biggest performance hit with a database is to filter out only the currently relevant data. If this has been done on the server side, sorting is quite easy on the client side.

Comment: Kien Chu you are correct but I do not know how to include the func in a dbquery statement. For example the methods I wrote that return IQueryable<T> can be used like a native linq extension. In this case I could code var output = _db.MyTable.MultiSort("field1,field2:desc").ToArray();

Comment: Experimenting I tried this,           q = q.OrderBy(x => MultipleSorts<T>(sortBy)); and got this error, LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Func`2[System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ORMModel.v_Brand],System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[ORMModel.v_Brand]] MultipleSorts[v_Brand](System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Just in case anybody else comes along looking for multiple level sorts I found this code easier to use. http://aonnull.blogspot.com/2010/08/dynamic-sql-like-linq-orderby-extension.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use method syntax, you'll see func quite often, for instance in `Where`, `GroupBy`, `Join`, etc

Every method with some input parameters and one return value can be translated to a `Func<...>` as follows

```
MyReturnType DoSomething(ParameterType1 p1, ParameterType2, p2) {...}

Func<ParameterType1, ParameterType2, MyReturnType> myFunc = (x, y) => DoSomething(x, y);
```

The part `Func<ParameterType1, ParameterType2, MyReturnType>` means: a function with two input parameters and one return value. The input parameters are of type `ParameterType1` and `ParameterType2`, in this order. The return value is of `MyReturnType`.

You instantiate an object of `Func<ParameterType1, ParameterType2, MyReturnType>` using a lambda expression. Before the `=>` you type a declaration for the input parameters, after the `=>` you call the function with these input parameters. If you have more than one input parameter you make them comma separated surrounded by brackets.

For a `Where` you need a `Func<TSource, bool>`. So a function that has as input one source element, and as result a bool:

```
Where(x => x.Name == "John Doe")
```

For a GroupJoin you need a resultSelector of type `Func<TOuter,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>,TResult> resultSelector`

So this is a function with as input one element of the outer sequence, and a sequence of elements of the inner sequence. For example, to query Teachers with their Students:

```
var result = Teachers.GroupJoin(Students,
    teacher => teacher.Id,           // from every Teacher take the Id,
    student => student.TeacherId,    // from every Student take the TeacherId,
    (teacher, students) => new
    {
        Id = teacher.Id,
        Name = teacher.Name,
        Students = students.Select(student => new
        {
            Id = student.Id,
            Name = student.Name,
        })
        .ToList(),
    });
```

Here you see several Funcs. TOuter is Teacher, TInner is Student, TKey is int

- OuterKeySelector: `Func<TOuter, TKey>`: teacher => teacher.Id
- InnerKeySelector: `Func<TInner, TKey>`: student => student.TeacherId
- ResultSelector: `Func<Touter, IEnumerable<TInner>, TResult>`

The resultSelector is a function that takes one TOuter (a Teacher), and a sequence of TInner (all students of this Teacher) and creates one object using the input parameters

```
(teacher, students) => new {... use teacher and students }
```

When creating the lambda expression it is often helpful if you use plurals to refer to collections (teachers, students) and singulars if you refer one element of a collection (student).

Use the `=>` to start defining the func. You can use input parameters that were defined before the `=>` to define the result after the `=>`